# Numbers validation in C

Tags: c

I need to write a little program in C, which recives only numbers.
As a part of this program I need to create a validation that user input will be only numbers,
otherwise the program should display an error.

I have read about the `isdigit()` function, but it's not working for me. Do you have other solutions for me?

`hours` and `minutes` are user input, and defined as integers.

```
if (!isdigit(hours) || !isdigit(minutes))
{
    printf("Invalid Time\n");
}
```

Comment: Whats `hours` and `minutes` ?

Comment: If the variables are defined as integers, they're always numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check every character of the input to determine if they are digits or not:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(hours); i++)
{
   if(!isDigit(hours[i])) { printf("invalid time\n"); break; }
}
```

Comment: Using strlen in a loop where the string doesn't change?  That's premature pessimization.

Comment: A decent compiler will certainly optimize it

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit` is only checking a single character; I suspect that you're looking at strings (although this isn't clear in your question).  I'm not sure whether there is library function that would do it for you, but you could use a function like:

```
int isnumeric(char *p)
{
   while (*p)
   {
       if ( ! isdigit(p))
           return 0;
       p++;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isdigit(X) return true if ( 0 <= X <= 9 ) in other words X is a digit not only a number.

what you want is reading the input into a string, and check if this string is a number and then convert it to a number using atoi(string).

Good Luck (: